# List pattern matching in Rascal

Tags: pattern-matching, rascal

In Haskell (and quite similar in Prolog / Erlang), we can define a length function over lists as:

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

In Rascal, I was able to create a definition like this using:

```
int length([]) = 0;
int length([x,xs*]) = 1 + length(xs);
```

The "*" disappears on the right hand side of the recursive case of length. I know that it might exist a reason for that, but I could not figure it out. Is there a better approach for defining recursive functions over lists using pattern matching in Rascal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various aspects of your question that I want to address:

1. Your Rascal version looks fine. Rascal has more general list pattern matching than Haskell: more than one variable can match more than one element, so each "list variable" in a list pattern has to be tagged with a `*` to indicate just that.
2. We are in a transitional phase where we are moving from the postfix * to a prefix *. So the second rule can be (and in the future should be) written as:

   `int length([x,*xs]) = 1 + length(xs);`
3. You may want to explore the *reducer expression* that can be used to write various fold-like functions:

   `int length(list[int] xs) = ( 0 | it + 1 | x <- xs );`

   It consists of three parts:

   - initial value (0); the built-in variable `it` is set to this initial value.
   - an expression that accumulates results and that may use `it`, here: `it + 1`. It has as effect `it = it + 1`.
   - an enumeration that produces the list elements.
4. More general (than simply head/tail) pattern matching examples are these:

   - `[*x, a]` : match the element at the end of a list
   - `[*x, *x]` : split the list in two equal halves
   - `[*a, x, *b, x, *c]` : find two duplicate elements
5. a bound list variable binds a full list which you can use like any other variable which points to a list, but if you want to splice it in on the right-hand side of the rule, you get a more symmetrical view: `int length([x,*xs]) = 1 + length([*xs]);`, of course this also generalizes, so this is also possible: `[*xs, 2, *xs]` where the `*` operator simply removes one layer of list nesting.

Comment: So... the "xs*" matches the tail of the list with "xs". In a more realistic scenario, when I was writing a transformation, I first considered that the tail of the list would be matched with "xs*", and thus spent several minutes to find the error. Thanks for your answer. I think that it will be nice to provide an example of pattern matching using lists in the Rascal Tutor (I could not find one).

Comment: There are examples in`demo::basic::Bubble`.

Comment: You can also find some examples here: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Patterns/Abstract/List/List.html. If you go to the tutor, these are under Patterns, Abstract, List (Abstract here meaning not patterns over concrete syntax).